# Show quadratic equation has two distinct real roots.

Tags: roots, quadratics

$x^2 - (5-k) x + (k+2) = 0  $ has two distinct real roots.

So, in the markscheme of this question, they take the discriminant ($-b^2 + 4ac$) and say it is greater than 0. That is, $( (-(5-k)^2 - 4(1)(k+2) > 0)$.

Then, they take its discriminant and say it is less than 0.

$36 - (4 * 32) < 0 $

And ,then they say it is true. I didn't understand how taking the discriminant of the discriminant helped prove.

Comment: The discriminant should be $b^2-4ac$ not what you wrote.

Comment: I imagine they want to find the cutoff values of $k$ for which there are two distinct roots. do you have the original source? If not, can you help me with my subscription to your magazine?

Comment: It should be $(5-k)^2$, not $-(5-k)^2$

Comment: @user99680, google IB Math HL exams. You get tons of interesting questions. And, if you're up for it, search for IB Further Math which is really intense. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first quadratic is in $x$ where you want the solutions to be real. Therefore the discriminant must be non-negative. Furthermore you want distinct real roots, therefore the discriminant must be positive.

When you compute the discriminant for the quadratic equation in $x$, you end up getting a quadratic expression in $k$. Then for it to be positive, you ended up with a quadratic inequality
$$(5-k)^2-4(k+2)>0$$
This is equivalent to 
$$k^2-14k+17 >0$$

Think of this as a parabola in $k$ and you want this parabola to be always above the $k-$axis. That means NO real solutions. For this the discriminant of this quadratic expression in $k$ must be negative.

PS: However please note that the last inequality is not true for all values of $k$. In fact
it is only true when 
$$k \in (-\infty, 7-4\sqrt{2}) \cup (7+4\sqrt{2}, \infty).$$
So for these values of $k$ the quadratic equation will have real roots.

Comment: Thank you! Understood it perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Showing that the discriminant is less than zero implies that there are no real solutions. So, if the discriminant has no real solutions, then it is greater than $0$. (That is $(5−k)^2 −4(1)(k+2)>0$ for all values of $k$.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the discriminant of the discriminant is not clarified in the accepted solution.

The discriminant of the quadratic equation $x^2-(5-k)x+(k+2)=0$ is $\Delta=k^2-14k+17$. We want $\Delta$ to be always positive, then the given equation will always have two distinct real roots.

For this to happen, the discriminant of $\Delta$ must be negative. But, the discriminant of $\Delta$ is $\Delta'=(-14)^2-4.17=128>0$ is positive. Therefore, the given quadratic equation has not always two distinct real roots but only if $k\in(-\infty,7-4\sqrt2)\cup(7+4\sqrt2,\infty)$ as found in the accepted answer.