# Show that the equation $2x^2+(6+p)x+3p=0$ has real roots for all real values of $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Show that the equation $2x^2+(6+p)x+3p=0$ has real roots for all real values of $p$.

My attempt,

$b^2-4ac=(6+p)^2-4(2)(3p)$

$=p^2-12p+36 $

$(p-6)^2 \geq 0$

Can I prove like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$p^2-2p\cdot6+6^2$$

Comment: There's someone saying that I must show that this form is larger or equal to 0 as the question says has real roots.

Comment: @vadim123 sorry had a typo just now

Answer (score 1):

You have one mistake in your solution.

In question term is $(6-p)$. But when you using it in formula you wrote it as $(6+p)$.

But your method to solve is correct. For two distinct real roots $b^2-4ac>0$

Comment: Sorry. Had a typo just now.

Comment: I think for real roots, it should be $b^2-4ac \geq 0$

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817729/show-quadratic-equation-has-two-distinct-real-roots

Comment: @Mathxx You are right. The question is not asking for **two distinct** roots, thus a repeated root is acceptable. Therefore, $\geq$ is suitable, not just $>$.

Comment: Yes hope projectilemotion cleared your doubt.

Comment: If two distinct roots we use >